# Generated pdf report in reportlab is not similar to original text data

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to generate a pdf document from a text file, but the out does not match the records on the textfile.

The pdf output data is starting from bottom of page rather than the top.

Please anyone have some ideas

below is the code:

Thanks in advance.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.colors import magenta, red

file = open("Computingdata.txt", "r")  # text file I need to convert
    lines = file.read()
file.close()

report = canvas.Canvas('mypdf4.pdf')#new pdf report i am creating
report.setFont("Times-Roman", 20)
report.setFillColor(red)
report.drawCentredString(150, 2.5*inch, "Student details")

report.setFillColor(magenta)
size = 12
y = 2.0*inch
#x = 1.3*inch
for line in lines.split(';'):
    report.setFont("Helvetica", size)
    report.drawString(30,y, line)
    y = y-size*1.2
    #size = size+0.5
report.save()
```

Just to add, the output comes in this form of
ID
USERID
LOGIN-NAME
PASSWORD
SURNAME
NAME
AGE:

Instead of 
ID       USERID      LOGIN-NAME      PASSWORD      SURNAME      NAME      AGE.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone, I have been able to solve all the problems  i experience with the adjusted code below:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
#from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.colors import magenta, red

file = open(""yourdata"", "r")  # text file I need to convert
lines = file.read()
file.close()
report = canvas.Canvas('mypdf5.pdf')#new pdf report i am creating
report.setFont("Times-Roman", 20)
report.setFillColor(red)
report.drawCentredString(100, 800, "Student details")

report.setFillColor(magenta)
size = 12
y = 790
#y = 2.0*inch
#x = 1.3*inch
for line in lines.split('\n'):
report.setFont("Helvetica", size)
    report.drawString(10, y, line)
    #y = y-size*1.2
    #size = size+0.5
    y = y - 10
report.save()
```

EDIT:
In the case whereby your input text file has so many delimiters, then you should do something like this

```
import re

file = open("yourdata", "r")  # text file I need to convert
lines = file.read()
lines2 = re.split('; |\n', lines)
file.close()
```

With the re package, you can include all delimiters to your text file making easy to display the exact content on the reportlab generated pdf file